# UICollectionView Height resizes on first load

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a UITableViewCell (`MyTableViewCell`) that contains a stackview. The first item in the stackview is a subview (`MyHeaderView`) which contains a few labels and a `UICollectionView`.
I have a problem when the tableview initially loads where the height of the `UICollectionView` is larger than the content and it then retracts/jumps to the correct size (the initial height is about twice that of the content). It also only happens when the items in the `UICollectionView` runs over more than 1 row.

```
class MyHeaderView: UIView {

    private var identifierLabel = UILabel()
    private var statementLabel = UILabel()
    private var referenceIdLabel = UILabel()

    private var tagsCollectionView: DynamicHeightCollectionView!

    private var tagsArray = [String]()
    private var tags = [String]()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() {
        initTagsCollectionViewLayout()

        backgroundColor = .red
        self.addSubview(contentView)
        contentView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.edges.equalToSuperview()
        }

        contentView.addSubview(identifierLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(tagsCollectionView)
        contentView.addSubview(statementLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(referenceIdLabel)

        identifierLabel.layer.borderWidth = 4
        identifierLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        identifierLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalToSuperview()
            make.leading.equalToSuperview()
            make.width.lessThanOrEqualTo(30)
            make.height.equalTo(30)
        }

        tagsCollectionView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(identifierLabel.snp.bottom)
            make.leading.equalToSuperview()
            make.trailing.equalToSuperview()
        }

        referenceIdLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        referenceIdLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(tagsCollectionView.snp.bottom)
            make.leading.equalToSuperview()
            make.trailing.equalToSuperview()
        }

        statementLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        statementLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(referenceIdLabel.snp.bottom)
            make.leading.equalToSuperview()
            make.trailing.equalToSuperview()
            make.bottom.equalToSuperview()
        }
    }

    lazy var contentView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 400))
        view.layer.borderWidth = 4
        view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        return view
    }()

    func initTagsCollectionViewLayout() {
        let flowLayout = LeftAlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout()

        tagsCollectionView = DynamicHeightCollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)

        tagsCollectionView.delegate = self
        tagsCollectionView.dataSource = self
        tagsCollectionView.isScrollEnabled = false
        tagsCollectionView.backgroundColor = .white

        flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 50, height: 20)
        flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 4
        flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 8
        flowLayout.scrollDirection = .vertical

        self.tagsCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = flowLayout
        self.tagsCollectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.tagsCollectionView.register(UINib.init(nibName: Constants.tagsCollectionCellNibName, bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: Constants.tagsCollectionCellReuseID)
    }

    // MARK: Set up view
    func setUpView(observation: Observation) {
        identifierLabel.text = observation.identifier
        statementLabel.text = observation.statement
        referenceIdLabel.text = observation.referenceID

        tagsArray = [String]()

        if let tags = observation.tags, tags.count > 0 {
            for tag in tags {
                tagsArray.append(tag)
            }
        }

        if tagsArray.count > 0 {
            tagsCollectionView.reloadData()
            //tagsCollectionView.setNeedsLayout()
            tagsCollectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }

    override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        if (self.superview != nil) {
            self.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
        }

        return tagsCollectionView.contentSize
    }
}

extension MyHeaderView: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tagsArray.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        var cell = UICollectionViewCell()

        switch collectionView {
        case tagsCollectionView:
            let tagsCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: Constants.tagsCollectionCellReuseID, for: indexPath) as! TagsCollectionViewCell

            tagsCollectionViewCell.initRequirementTag(tagText: self.tagsArray[indexPath.item])

            cell = tagsCollectionViewCell

        default:
            break
        }

        return cell
    }
}

// MARK: - Constants
private enum Constants {
    static let tagsCollectionCellReuseID = "TagsCollectionViewCell"
    static let tagsCollectionCellNibName = "TagsCollectionViewCell"
}








class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    private var stackView = UIStackView()
    private var myHeaderView = MyHeaderView()
    private var observation: Observation?


    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() {
        self.addSubview(stackView)

        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.spacing = 4
        stackView.distribution = .fillProportionally
        stackView.alignment = .fill
        stackView.arrangedSubviews.forEach({ $0.removeFromSuperview() }) // clear stack view on each load

        stackView.addArrangedSubview(myHeaderView)

        stackView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.edges.equalToSuperview()
            //make.width.equalToSuperview()
        }

        myHeaderView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.edges.equalToSuperview()
        }

    }

    func setupView(observation: Observation) {
        self.observation = observation

        myHeaderView.setUpView(observation: observation)
    }

}





class DynamicHeightCollectionView: UICollectionView {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        if !__CGSizeEqualToSize(bounds.size, self.intrinsicContentSize) {
            self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        }
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return contentSize
    }
}

class LeftAlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)

        var leftMargin = sectionInset.left
        var maxY: CGFloat = -1.0
        attributes?.forEach { layoutAttribute in
            if layoutAttribute.frame.origin.y >= maxY {
                leftMargin = sectionInset.left
            }

            layoutAttribute.frame.origin.x = leftMargin

            leftMargin += layoutAttribute.frame.width + minimumInteritemSpacing
            maxY = max(layoutAttribute.frame.maxY , maxY)
        }

        return attributes
    }
}




// in tableview controller
var obs1 = Observation(identifier: "1.1", statement: "custom statement test", referenceID: "reference id test", tags: ["tag 1", "tag 2", "tag 3", "tag 4", "tag 5", "tag 6", "tag 7", "tag 8", "tag 9", "tag 10", "tag 11", "tag 12", "tag 13", "tag 14", "tag 15", "tag 16", "tag 17", "tag 18", "tag 19", "tag 20"])

    var obs2 = Observation(identifier: "1.2", statement: "custom statement test thats runs onto multiple lines, custom statement test thats runs onto multiple lines, custom statement test thats runs onto multiple lines, custom statement test thats runs onto multiple lines", referenceID: "reference id test that runs onto multiple lines, reference id test that runs onto multiple lines reference id test that runs onto multiple lines reference id test that runs onto multiple lines reference id test that runs onto multiple lines", tags: ["tag 1", "tag 2", "tag 3", "tag 4", "tag 5", "tag 6", "tag 7", "tag 8"])

    var obs3 = Observation(identifier: "1.3", statement: "custom statement test", referenceID: "reference id test", tags: [])

    var obs4 = Observation(identifier: "1.4", statement: "custom statement test", referenceID: "reference id test", tags: [])

var obs: [Observation]
obs.append(obs1)
obs.append(obs2)
obs.append(obs3)
obs.append(obs4)

struct Observation {
    var identifier: String
    var statement: String
    var referenceID: String
    var tags: [String]
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ObservationTableViewCellV2") as! ObservationTableViewCellV2

        let observation = obs[indexPath.row] as! Observation
        cell.setupView(observation: observation)

        return cell
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return obs.count
    }
```

I have tried changing the estimated item size and the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` `sizeForItemAt` but it makes no difference.

The `UICollectionView` is highlighted in blue. On first load it appears as:
[image]

Then a split second later it resizes to the correct size:
[image]

Comment: can you please show a screenshot of your problem.

Comment: Images attached

Comment: Tried to debug your code, run into multiple errors, can you update the question with a [mcve]?

Comment: Added in some additional data. Is this enough or is more required?

Comment: @KvnH try adding the code from the question in a new project, and once you make that project build and exhibit the bad behaviour, you can put the updated code in the question. There are still build errors in your code, like `snp` not found, a minimal reproducible example would mean working code, or trivial to make a working from yours.

Comment: Hi @KvnH have you solved this issue? i am experienced this jumping behaviour right now.

Answer (score 0):

In storyboard inside Size Inspector section make `Estimate Size` on the Collection View from `Automatic` to `None`.

Comment: I am not using storyboard.

Comment: use layoutIfNeeded() from the parent view of collection view

Answer (score 0):

When you dequeue the cell that contains the collection view, check its width. It is probably smaller than the width of the tableview (maybe 320?). Set it to something larger like the tableView's width for example in `cellForRowAt indexPath:` as soon as you dequeue it, so the collection view can calculate it's height correctly. After you set it's width and the collectionView is added, call `layoutIfNeeded()`

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, if it is resizing to what you want 'a split second later' then the code is working and I can only assume you need to look at when the code is running.

I had a similar simple issue where I had put some resizing logic in `viewDidAppear` rather than in `viewWillAppear`. Making that simple change made all the difference.

Answer (score -1):

Try to explicitly run layoutIfNeeded on the main thread inside of initTagsCollectionViewLayout. That could be the issue here.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   self.tagsCollectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```